# Peano axioms-Analysis I by Terence Tao

Tags: natural-numbers, peano-axioms

**Statement**: Terence Tao in his book Analysis I states that the set N = {0,0.5,1,1.5,2,...} satisfies peano axioms 1 to 4.
**Axiom 2**: if n is a natural number, n++ is also a natural number
**Definition 2.1.3**: 0++ =1, 1++ = 2,2++ = 3
**my understanding** : because of definition 2.1.3, the set N in the statement doesn’t satisfy axiom 2.
**My question** : why did Tao state that set N satisfies all 4 axioms. What maybe the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Include in your question what the axioms actually state, please.

Comment: Why don't you think that satisfies axiom 2?   If we define $x++$ as "the next in the list" then it is $x++ = x + 0.5$. and if $x \in N$ then $x++ = x + 0.5$ is certainly in the list.  So axiom 2 holds.  (Axiom 2 is that if $x\in \mathbb N$ then $x++\in \mathbb N$)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Oh... I think I was mistaken by what "increment" ($x++$) meant according to Tao.  He meant $x++ = x + 1$ (I think).  Axiom 2 still holds.  If $x \in \{0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5,....\}$ then if $x+1 \in  \{0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5,....\}$.  [The reason I *think* Tao means $x++ = x+1$ rather than "next in the list" is that if he mean "next in the list" Axiom 5 the induction axiom *would* hold and in fact $\{0, 0.1, 1, 1.5,...\}$ *IS* the natural number only with the *name*s of every number changed.]  .... But we *really* need to have this question expressed in *full* detail to understand it.

Comment: OP: Hi! If @fleablood is correct in stating Axiom $2$, can you please put it in the original post? Thanks!

Comment: I will answer this question for you after you rewrite the question in a way that anyone who has never read and doesn't have a copy of Tao's book will understand what you are asking.

Comment: The text of Tao's book is here (https://math.unm.edu/~crisp/courses/math401/tao.pdf) by the way.  But I am probably going too far in trying to answer a badly worded question.  It is up to the poster to ask a question in a manner that the question is self-contained.

Comment: @fleablood I have edited the question. Hope I have made it more clear

Answer (score 0):

On pages 17 and 18 Tao casually (non)defines $n++$ as "the successor" which means counting forward.  $0++$ counting forward is $1$ and $2++$ counting forward is $3$ and so on.  (This is an intuitive definition for the sake of making what is a purely abstract concept to mathematician, a solid example to a novice student.)

As such if we were to talk about the successor of *non*-integers $x++$ would be what we think of as $x+1$.  So $\pi++ = \pi + 1 = 4.141592653......$.

Now his idea, (which I guess is a good one) is rather than introduce the natural numbers purely by abstract Peano postulates where we say "$\mathbb N$ is a set.  We don't *anything* about it except it obeys the axioms: $0$ is a in $\mathbb N$.  We don't know what $0$ is.  It's just a thing.  Every thing $n$ in the set has the concept of there being another element $n++$.  We don't know what that means that just a concept, but ...".   Instead Tao seems to say "Look, we all know that $\mathbb N = \{0,1,2,3,.....\}$ and that we or just *counting*.  But what does that *mean*?  How can we formalize that."

Okay.   Suppose we have two sets $\mathbb N = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,......\}$ and $N'= \{0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, .....\}$.

Axiom 1. $0 \in \mathbb N$.  That's clearly true for how we listed $\mathbb N$.  And for our made up set $N'$ it appears also to be true.

Axiom 2. If $n\in \mathbb N$ then $n++\in \mathbb N$.  That is clearly true for $\mathbb N$.  $0\in \mathbb N$ and $0++ = 1 \in \mathbb N$ and $1\in \mathbb N$ and $1++ =2 \in \mathbb N$ and so on.

*AND IT IS ALSO TRUE FOR N'*.  $0 \in N'$ and $0++=1\in N'$.  And $0.5\in N'$ and $0.5++ = 1.5\in N'*$ and so on.

....

so that's your answer

.....

It's also clear that Axioms 3 and 4 hold.

Axiom 3: $0$ is not equal to any $n \in \mathbb N$.

It is also true that $0$ is not a successor to any element of $N'$.  As long as we are cheating by assuming we know things about numbers (that *is* very unorthodox of Tao to do so, but I must admit it probably is *much* easier on the novice student) we know $(-1)++ = 0$ and $-1 \not \in \mathbb N$ and $-1 \not \in N'$.

Axiom 4:  Different elements of $\mathbb N$ must have different successors. If $m\ne n$ then $m++ \ne n++$. And if $m++ \ne n++$ then $m \ne n$.

That's true for both cases.

As all true for both $\mathbb N$ and $N'$ (and for $\mathbb Q^+$ or $\mathbb R^+$).  In fact these axioms are true for any sets that have $0,1,2,3,4,.....$ and any other extra values so long as if it has $x$ it also has $x+1, x+2, x+3,....$ and so long as it doesn't have $-1$.

So what allows us to say $\mathbb N$ is *just* $0,1,2,3,4,.... $ and not any of these other sets?

That'd be axiom 5.  The induction axiom.

If $P(0)$ is true.  And $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$ [which means $P(0), P(1), P(2), P(3)..... $ etc. must all be true] then we have to have it true for all elements in the set.

This fails for $N'$ as, we could conclude $P(0), P(1), P(2)...$ etc or true we have no reason to thing $P(0.5)$ is true.  This axiom basically says, $\mathbb N$ contains only the terms we can count to from $0$ and nothing more.  We can count to the half integers so the half integers are not part of the natural numbers.

Comment: Now I get it. Many thanks